# I have an error : Property 'form' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
 
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }

}
```

**Error**
`error TS2564: Property 'form' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell the compiler to rest assured that the member will be initialized.

```js
form!: FormGroup;
```

It is best to not turn off *strictPropertyInitialization*, as suggested in the top answer of the referred link.